# CPython API jiving with C++ class

Tags: c++, python, api

I'm trying to use structs defined in the C/Python API in a C++ class. Specifically, I'm trying to define an array of structures for `PyMethodDef` and `PyMemberDef` (documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.8/c-api/structures.html?highlight=pymemberdef#PyMethodDef)):

For `PyMethodDef`, I am able to define a static array in a class header and declare it in the implementation file. However, doing the same thing for `PyMemberDef` gives me the following errors:

```
error: elements of array 'PyMemberDef members_ []' have incomplete type
error: storage size of 'members_' isn't known.
```

I think I can see why `PyMethodDef` works but `PyMemberDef` does not. In the Python source, `PyMethodDef` is defined as such:

```
struct PyMethodDef {
    ...
    ...
};

typedef struct PyMethodDef PyMethodDef;
```

whereas `PyMemberDef` is defined as such:

```
typedef struct PyMemberDef {
   ...
   ...
} PyMemberDef;
```

I confirmed this to be the cause of the problem by defining `PyMemberDef` the way `PyMethodDef` is in my code and confirming that it compiles without error. However, I don't know how to rectify this. I would prefer not to hardcode and redefine it myself.
Hope this is clear enough. I can provide more detail upon request.
Thanks.

Comment: g++ on a 64 bit linux machine

Comment: Hmm, I've just tried with clang, and it gives also: `/usr/include/python2.7/object.h:381:12: note: forward declaration of 'PyMemberDef'`, `struct PyMemberDef *tp_members;`… give me a minute to think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you tried with clang, it would give you a bit more meaningful error message like:

```
pymountboot.cxx:45:20: error: variable has incomplete type 'PyMemberDef'
static PyMemberDef foo_members[] = {
                   ^
/usr/include/python2.7/object.h:381:12: note: forward declaration of 'PyMemberDef'
    struct PyMemberDef *tp_members;
           ^
1 error generated.
```

So, it seems that `PyMemberDef` is not actually declared here.

A quick grep shows that it is declared in `structmember.h`, and that file is not included in `Python.h`.

Then a quick look at the Python docs on [Defining new types](http://docs.python.org/extending/newtypes.html#adding-data-and-methods-to-the-basic-example) and you could notice that the example starts with:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "structmember.h"
```

Comment: Thanks. For those on a standard Linux system install with Python 3.5, <python3.5m/structmember.h>